# Understand oracle convertion function

Tags: oracle

Why this statement produces an error? I'm surprises to meet an error

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(1890.55,'$9,999D99') FROM DUAL;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please specify which error you get.

Answer (score 1):

Is it the *thousands* separator? Compare!

```
SQL> SELECT TO_CHAR(1890.55,'$9,999D99') FROM DUAL;
SELECT TO_CHAR(1890.55,'$9,999D99') FROM DUAL
                       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01481: invalid number format model


SQL> SELECT TO_CHAR(1890.55,'$9G999D99') FROM DUAL;

TO_CHAR(18
----------
 $1.890,55

SQL>
```

**[EDIT]**

You should know what character represents a thousands separator, and which one is a decimal point character. If you include yet another parameter into the `TO_NUMBER` function - `NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS`, and set it to reflect value you're converting, then it *works*:

```
SQL> select TO_NUMBER('30470.73', '99999D99', 'nls_numeric_characters=''.,''') res
  2  from dual;

       RES
----------
  30470,73

SQL>
```

Comment: But according to some books i have read, "," and 'G' are thousands separator? Is it extact ? Exemple: select to_char(03040,'$09999,99') from dual; work

Comment: @steve when you put G on the format mask , the thousand seperator symbol is determined by OS environment variables.

Comment: Interestingly [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-096CA64F-1DA3-4C49-A18B-ECC7518EE56C) don't say that mixing literals (`.` and `,`) with the NLS placeholders (`D` and `G`) isn't allowed, and even kind of imply it is - "A comma cannot appear to the right of a decimal character or period in a number format model", suggesting it *can* appear to the left of `D`. MoS not-a-bug 1204892 explains why it isn't allowed though.

Comment: `select TO_NUMBER('30470.73', '99999D9') from dual;` <br/>
 `select TO_NUMBER('30470.73', '99999D9') from dual
                 *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01722: invalid number` @A

Comment: I've added some more info into my message; have a look, please.